# Should we merge [digital-audio] and [mp3] to [digital] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think that [mp3](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mp3) and [digital-audio](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-audio) could be merged because mp3 is included in digital audio and there is no need to distinguish every possible digital format.

Also, I suggest to shorten the tag [digital-audio](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-audio) to [digital](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital) because "audio" is kind of redundant since we are in a music fans community.

Answer (score 1):

I think the topic needs to be discussed, but I don't think this is the right solution. The term digital audio refers to almost every form of music we have now a days. For example, [cd](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd)s are digital media with a physical copy so getting rid of the mp3 tag and not also getting rid of the cd tag weakens the association with the real term.

Digital alone is also too ambiguous and can be applied in very poor ways. For example if people had a question about how bands can do a live streaming performance online a new user might just tag it with digital because the performance is digital. There are other questions that could pop up in this vein.